# What to do with these old-style casts?

Tags: c++, casting

I'm getting a few "use of old-style cast" warnings which I would like to get rid of, but I don't know enough about this.

Edit:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is indeed defined in the WinAPI so I will leave that one alone.

`(LPBYTE)&result`: `LPBYTE(&result)` and `reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&result)` work, but I have no idea if either is equivalent.
So which of these three do I use?

`(const BYTE*)&value`: `reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&value)` works, but same thing again.
So which of these two do I use?

Some more context:

```
HKEY hKey;
std::string sResult = "";
if(regOpenKey(KEY_READ, &hKey))
{
    DWORD size=1024, type = REG_SZ;
    wchar_t result[MAX_PATH];
    if(RegQueryValueEx(hKey, key, nullptr, &type, (LPBYTE)&result, &size) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        sResult = str_narrow(result);
}

RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

and:

```
HKEY hKey;
if(regOpenKey(KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey))
{
    DWORD value = 1;
    RegSetValueEx(hKey, key, 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&value, sizeof(value));
}

RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Shouldn't these be defined by the Windows headers?

Comment: In general terms,  the "old-style cast  `(type)something` is equivalent to `type(something)`.    From the information you provide (which isn't really enough, so I may be wrong) all examples except the last could be done as `static_cast<type>(something)` which is considered by some to be more idiomatic C++.    Casting a fixed integral value to a pointer and then dereferencing is formally undefined behaviour though, so read your compiler/library documentation carefully.

Comment: I've updated my question. `static_cast` doesn't work in these examples. It's still not clear to me which method is preferable.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is defined in the WinAPI, so leave it alone. It could change without warning (although unlikely, but possible).

> `(LPBYTE)&result: LPBYTE(&result)` works, but again, I have no idea if it's equivalent.

Yes, its the same.

> `(const BYTE*)&value: reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&value)` works, but same thing again.

The same again.

Comment: maybe worth mentioning that a `reinterpret_cast` may silence a warning, but should be considered a red flag just as the c-style cast (it is basically the replacement for a c-style cast, when no other x_cast applies)

Comment: `LPBYTE(&result)` is not a C-style cast.   It is specific to C++, and not valid in standard C.    However, the `_cast` conversions are often considered preferable in C++.

Comment: So should I stick with the C-style cast or use use `reinterpret_cast`? In the case of `(LPBYTE)&result`, should I use `LPBYTE(&result)` or `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @bur What type is `result` of?

Comment: `wchar_t result[MAX_PATH]`

Comment: @bur `reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(result)` - no need for the address-of operator there.